# C# WPF refresh listbox from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh

I'm making a WPF project based on an Access database.
The database has two tables:

> - tblMovies (MovieID: PK, Title, Director, Genre etc)
> - tblActors (ActorID: PK, MovieID: FK, Firstname, Lastname etc)

I have listbox where I can see all the movies, and if I click on one, it shows a new window with all the details about that movie: the title, director, genre, but also the actors.

In this window I have added a button to create a new actor. This opens a new window where you can enter the MovieID (FK) and the information about the actor.
When I click save changes, it works and the window closes, but my listboxActors needs to be manually refreshed (I have added a button for that) to see the new actor.

Is there a way to refresh my listboxActors after I click "save changes" in my other window?

I first did it by closing my first screen when clicking add new actor, and then if I saved it would reopen the screen, and it'd automatically be refreshed, but I don't want it that way.

My listboxActors:

```
        listBoxActors.ItemsSource = mov.Actors;
```

Save button (in the other screen)

```
    private void buttonSaveNewActor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Actor act = new Actor();
            act.MovieID = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMovieID.Text);
            act.FirstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
            act.LastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
            act.Country = textBoxCountry.Text;
            act.Born = Convert.ToDateTime(BornDate.SelectedDate);
            act.Bio = textBoxBio.Text;
            ActorRepository.AddActor(act);
            MessageBox.Show("The actor: " + act.FirstName + " " + act.LastName + " has been created");
            this.Hide();
        }
```

The refresh button:

```
    private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxActors.ItemsSource = null;
        listBoxActors.ItemsSource = mov.Actors;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me clarify these, The `buttonSaveNewActor_Click` is in the actor add form and `buttonRefresh_Click` is in the Movie form, isn't it? then  what is `mov` here?

Comment: Yes, there are two windows:

- WindowShowDetails: this has two listboxes, one with information about the movie, and one with the actors
- WindowAddActor: enter movieID, name etc. This has a save button that closes the screen, and then in the details window the actor is added to the listboxactors (but it requires a manual refresh to show).


        public WindowShowDetails(Movie mov)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.mov = mov;
            listBoxMovies.ItemsSource = detaillist; //selfmade
            listBoxActors.ItemsSource = mov.Actors;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Thanks for the explanatory comment...! I have a suggestion for you, please let me know if this helps you to code your scenario:

So you have two forms `WindowShowDetails` Let it be the main-form and `WindowAddActor` be the child, the Their will be a button in the main form which opens the child form, and you are doing some tasks in the child and press the Save button, which will save those details and closes that form. And you wanted to refresh the List in the main form associated with this event. For this you can use delegates and events;For this you have to do a number of tasks, in the main-form as well as in the child, Let me show you how it can help you:

- Define a delegate in the main form:

  ```
  public delegate void RefreshList();
  ```
- Define an event of that delegate type

  ```
  public event RefreshList RefreshListEvent;
  ```
- Define a method that will do the action(ie, Refreshing the grid)

  ```
  private void RefreshListView()
  {
      // Code to refresh the grid
  }
  ```
- Now need to define a Delegate in the `WindowAddActor`

  Public Delegate UpdateActor;
- Now we have to code the button click that opens the `WindowAddActor` form Let the button be `btnAddActor` so its Click event will be `btnAddActor_click`, we have to initialize our delegate-event, the instance of the `WindowAddActor` and assign the event to Delegate in the `WindowAddActor` before showing that form. this can be coded as :

  ```
   private void btnAddActor_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        WindowAddActor actorInstance = new WindowAddActor();      
        RefreshListEvent += new RefreshList(RefreshListView); // event initialization
        actorInstance.UpdateActor =  RefreshListEvent; // assigning event to the Delegate
        actorInstance.Show(); 
   }
  ```
- Now we have to call the delegate from the SaveButton's click event that is

  ```
  private void buttonSaveNewActor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     // Perform save operation 
     UpdateActor.DynamicInvoke(); this will call the `RefreshListView` method of mainWindow

     this.Close();
  }
  ```

Comment: Took me a while to understand what was going on, as I was not familiar with Delegate, but I got it to work.

Thank you very much for your time and in-depth instructions!!

Comment: Its ok.. Happy to help you