# Enable Form1 when you close Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not new in C#.Net but I'm a little bit confused about communication of multiple forms. Anyway, this is all I want to do.

1. Open a form2 when I click the button1 in form1.
2. form2 will appear and form1 will be disabled but won't be closed.
3. Close the form2 when I click its close button and form1 will be enabled.

Comment: Yes! I've tried it
            frm1.enabled = true
            this.Hide();
doesn't work :(

Comment: You should use delegates to make this work, I have [answered a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420633/c-sharp-wpf-refresh-listbox-from-another-window/41421004#41421004) you can use the same concept to code your scenario

Comment: If you show Form2 as [dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx), behavior 2 & 3 is built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form2.ShowDialog();` instead of `form2.Show();`.

Answer (score 0):

On your form2 add Event if the Window Close or add it to your button `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`

On your form1 use ShowDialog instead of Show

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

After Showdialoug you can use this

```
        if ( dr == DialogResult.OK ){// Do Something}
```

Inside the If you can still grab Datas from Public string,ints... out of Form2. And do Something as reaction. I mostly use this if the secound form close.

Example:

```
            AddForm3 addfrm = new AddForm3();
            addfrm.adr = adr;
            addfrm.user = user;
            addfrm.pwd = pwd;
            addfrm.dat = dat;
            addfrm.tbl = tbl;

            DialogResult dr = addfrm.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
```

Comment: Um, looks like you accidentally slipped into German there. Can you translate the second half of your answer into English? This is an English-only website!